# TokBox iOS - App Background process singal not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, tokbox

We are facing some strange issue in the iOS app , we are handling the signal when app in background mode.

It's perfectly working in xcode simulator and the same thing it's not working in real iOS devices. The signals not receiving in app background mode.

Do we need to enable any settings in iOS devices to handle this?

And, It's perfectly working in android devices.

Please help on this.
(Also Project->Capabilities-> Background Modes -> Audio,AirPlay,PIP  is enabled for this to work in background.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps sent to the background are generally expected to get suspended unless there is a reason for the process to stay running. In the case of using the OpenTok SDK, usually this means the app will be suspended *unless* there is a Publisher and/or Subscriber running -- background permission is tied to the AVAudioSession.

If you are trying to just keep a session connected without any subscribers/publishers while the app is in the background, this is not a recommended implementation. Keeping a websocket active for an OpenTok session requires trickling data every few seconds, creating an unnecessary burden on energy and data costs. For this reason, it is recommended to do your offline signaling via APNS rather than through an OpenTok session.

I trust you may have already seen this, but just for completeness, a more in-depth writeup on the topic is available here: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/background-state.html

Disclosure: I work for TokBox.

Comment: We are not able to received signal in Background mode. When app in foreground mode, all the messages are received.
[OTSessionDelegate session:receivedSignalType:fromConnection:withString:]  ::: Could you please let me know, is it possible to Receiving signals in a session in iOS App Background mode? its working in Android app as well as iOS simulator. why is not working in real iOS devices?

Comment: The app is probably being suspended while in the background, for the reasons I mentioned above. While the process is suspended, there will be no network activity, and therefore no signals received.

Comment: @Poornima https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html can you give a general idea if you are interested